# System.NullReferenceException (Visual Studio 2012, ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I apologize if the question is poorly executed, this is my first post here. I am a newbie at using Visual Studio and ASP.NET, I admit that, and have been sitting with this error a while.

I'm trying to create a form with 5 questions and 5 text boxes where you can fill in your answers and then when you click a button the answers will be saved in a table in my database. The problem is that I get an error *after* clicking the button. This is my code:

```
namespace uppg3
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String minSkola = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["school"];
            Label1.Text = minSkola;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (svarDatabasEntities datakoppling = new svarDatabasEntities())
            {
                    var nySvar = new Svar();
                    nySvar.svar1 = Box1.Text;
                    nySvar.svar2 = Box2.Text;
                    nySvar.svar3 = Box3.Text;
                    nySvar.svar4 = Box4.Text;
                    nySvar.svar5 = Box5.Text;
                    datakoppling.Svar.Add(nySvar);
                    datakoppling.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error message I get:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Objektreferensen har inte angetts till en instans av ett objekt.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Objektreferensen har
> inte angetts till en instans av ett objekt.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 26:                     nySvar.svar4 = Box4.Text;
>
> Line 27:                     nySvar.svar5 = Box5.Text;
>
> Line 28:                     **datakoppling.Svar.Add(nySvar);**
>
> Line 29:                     datakoppling.SaveChanges();
>
> Line 30:             }
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Ann-Helén\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2012\Projects\uppg3\default.aspx.cs    Line: 28
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Objektreferensen har inte angetts till en
> instans av ett objekt.]    uppg3._default.Button1_Click(Object sender,
> EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Ann-Helén\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2012\Projects\uppg3\default.aspx.cs:28
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +158
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +174
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +39
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
> sourceControl, String eventArgument) +37
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
> +105    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +4411

@Oded: Thank you for the reply! I tried out your suggestion, but unfortunately got the same error. However, I noted something in the program now:

[image: Error image]

UPDATE:

A new idea put froward is that the text boxes are null. Now I got the idea from someone else that the page_load resets the text boxes and will try to find a solution to this. Thank you all for your help, I'll update this with the solution if this is it.

Comment: Looks like `datakoppling.Svar` is null

Comment: @Justin: it says line 28, so `Box5` is null

Comment: Can you give us the code for the svarDatabasEntities class? Specifically the getter for Svar, something like this List<SVar> Svar { get { some code; } set { some more code; }

Comment: @Martin: svarDatabasEntities is the Entity Framework thingie I use to connect with my database. Svar is a table in the database.

Comment: My bad, I noted the formatting was deceptive! I edited the question to make it clearer what line 28 is ;p

Answer (score 0):

`datakoppling.Svar` is never assigned to, so is `null`.

Instead of:

```
datakoppling.Svar.Add(nySvar);
```

Do:

```
datakoppling.Svar = new DbSet<Svar>();
datakoppling.Svar.Add(nySvar);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried it out but got the same error though. I've updated the main post with a link to a new discovery: http://i.imgur.com/1cQJvMo.png

Comment: @Zarkaylia - It is clear from the error that `datakoppling.Svar` is a `DbSet<uppg3.Svar>`, not a `uppg3.Svar`. Answer updated.

Comment: it says line 28, so `Box5` is null

Comment: @Oded: It complains on DbSet unfortunately.

Comment: @leppie: That would mean it doesn't fetch the input text properly and I'd guess you might be onto something here. Why fetching the text doesn't work though, no idea.

Comment: My bad, I noted the formatting was deceptive! I edited the question to make it clearer what line 28 is ;p